# Koajs: How to check current connection is over https or not?

Tags: https, koa

I am using koajs, I have a router like the following and I want to detect if user is requesting via https, how can I achieve it?

```js
router.get('/video', function(next){
  if(request is over https) {
      this.body = yield render('/video', {});
  } else {
      this.redirect('https://example.com/video');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `secure` which is attached to the context's `request` object. It's also aliased onto the `ctx` itself.

Koa v1:

```
router.get('/video', function *(next) {
  if (this.secure) {
    // The request is over https
  }
})
```

Koa v2:

```
router.get('/video', async (ctx, next) => {
  if (ctx.secure) {
    // The request is over https
  }
})
```

`ctx.secure` is equivalent to checking that `ctx.protocol === "https"`.

This is all mentioned in the [Koa website docs](http://koajs.com/#request-secure), I would definitely recommend checking there first whenever you have a Koa-related question.